# javascript for a specific view

Tags: php, jquery, cakephp

I have a javascript code that should only run in `app/Clients/show_products.ctp`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Do stuff
});
```

Should I to put this in layout or in the end of the view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put it in the `app/Clients/show_products.ctp` view, using [scriptBlock](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html#HtmlHelper%3a%3ascriptBlock)

```
$this->Html->scriptBlock('
    $(document).ready(function(){
        //Do stuff
    });
');
```

You can specify to display the code inline or not.
If you need it in more than one places, you can use an [element](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#elements)

Adding it on the bottom of the view would be ok.

If you have a lot of code, it's better to create a `js` file for it.

Comment: Anywhere in the view should be a good practice, or should I put this in the end of the view? thanks

Comment: I added a few more notes to the answer